# C++ linker cannot find reference to local functions

Tags: c++, function, linker

I have this simple code inserted in myfile.hpp file inside a project of mine:

```
#ifndef _PERFORMANCE_INDEX_HPP_
#define _PERFORMANCE_INDEX_HPP_

#include <boost/math/special_functions/powm1.hpp>
#include <boost/math/special_functions/log1p.hpp>
#include <boost/math/special_functions/sqrt1pm1.hpp>

//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Enum, struct, aliases
namespace middleware {
namespace calculus {
/*!
 * Parameters needed for calculating PI.
 */
typedef struct {
    double eval_cpu_mhz; /* CPU MHz */
    double eval_ram_mb; /* RAM in MegaBytes */
    unsigned int eval_core_num; /* Number of cores per processor */
    unsigned int eval_cpu_num; /* Number of processors */
    unsigned int eval_hops; /* INET hop distance */
    double eval_bandwidth; /* Bandwidth in KBit/s */
    unsigned int eval_load; /* Number of tasks in queue in worker */
} PerformanceEvalParams;
/*!
 * PI type.
 */
typedef double PIType;
}
}
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Constants
namespace middleware {
namespace calculus {
const double kPerformanceEvalBeta = 3.0;
const double kPerformanceEvalDelta = 1.0;
const double kPerformanceEvalG = 1.60;
const double kPerformanceEvalH = 1.014;
const double kPerformanceEvalR = 512;
}
}
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Functions declarations
namespace middleware {
namespace calculus {
/*!
 * Used to calculate log in a given base.
 */
double Log(double base, double arg);
/*!
 * Used to calculate sqrt.
 */
double Sqrt(double arg);
/*!
 * Used to calculate exp by a given base.
 */
double Exp(double base, double arg);
/*!
 * Used for calculate PI
 */
PIType CalulatePI(const PerformanceEvalParams& pep);
}
}
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Functions implementations
using namespace middleware::calculus;
PIType CalculatePI(const PerformanceEvalParams& pep) {
    double N = -1, S = -1, C = -1; /* Parts */
    double PI = -1; /* Final result */
    N = (double)(kPerformanceEvalBeta * pep.eval_bandwidth);
    N = (double)(N / (double)((kPerformanceEvalDelta * (pep.eval_hops + 1))));
    N = (double)(Sqrt(N));
    S = (double)(pep.eval_cpu_mhz * pep.eval_cpu_num);
    S = (double)(S / ((double)(pep.eval_load + 1)));
    C = Log(kPerformanceEvalG, pep.eval_core_num);
    C = (double)(C + 1);
    C = (double)((double)1 + Exp(kPerformanceEvalH, -(pep.eval_ram_mb - 512)));
    PI = (double)(N * S * C);
    return PI;
}
double Log(double base, double arg) {
    // Boost Log returns boost::math::log1p(x) = log(e, x + 1)
    double res = (double)(boost::math::log1p(arg - 1));
    // Base conversion: log(new, y) = log(old, y) / log(old, new)
    // Then ==> log(base, arg) = log(e, arg) / log(e, base)
    res = (double)(res / boost::math::log1p(base));
    return res;
}
double Sqrt(double arg) {
    // Boost Sqrt returns boost::math::sqrt1pm1(x) = sqrt(1 + x) - 1
    double res = (double)(boost::math::sqrt1pm1(arg - 1));
    res = (double)(res + 1);
    return res;
}
double Exp(double base, double arg) {
    // Boost Pow returns boost::math::powm1(x, y) = x^y - 1
    double res = (double)(boost::math::powm1(base, arg));
    res = (double)(res + 1);
    return res;
}

#endif
```

I compile using this compilation directive:

> g++ *.cpp

In main.cpp notice that there is #include "myfile.hpp", so it is compiled.

g++ tells me this:

> /tmp/ccY04BAx.o: In function
>   `CalculatePI(middleware::calculus::PerformanceEvalParams
>   const&)': main.cpp:(.text+0x1edd):
>   undefined reference to`
>   middleware::calculus::Sqrt(double)'
>   main.cpp:(.text+0x1f43): undefined
>   reference to
>   `middleware::calculus::Log(double,
>   double)' main.cpp:(.text+0x1f72):
>   undefined reference to`
>   middleware::calculus::Exp(double,
>   double)' collect2: ld returned 1 exit
>   status

What's the problem? Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your functions *declarations* are in namespace `middleware::calculus`, your functions *definitions* are not.

The `using` declarations you added before the implementations is not of any help here (and is by the way, generally not recommended in a header file), and surely doesn't mean that omitting the namespace in the definitions will implicitly 'match' the declarations.

Comment: Yes you're absolutely right... crystal clear, I was in a hurry and didn't think this was an hpp file... thank you :)

Comment: +1: @Andry: There are two issues, the first of which is that you should never use the `using namespace` in a header, but the main issue is not that, but the fact that after `using namespace middleware::calculus;`, defining a function `Exp` (to give an example) will define `::Exp`, and not `::middleware::calculus::Exp` even if the later was declared earlier on. That is a good reason to always open namespaces when defining elements within, even if in the case of member functions the compiler will be able to locate the right type for you with the `using namespace`.

Answer (score 2):

```
using namespace middleware::calculus;
PIType CalculatePI(const PerformanceEvalParams& pep)
```

This does not define the `CalculatePI` function that you previously declared inside of the `middleware::calculus` namespace.  This declares and defines a new function in the global namespace.

You either need to qualify the function name in the definition:

```
using namespace middleware::calculus;
PIType middleware::calculus::CalculatePI(const PerformanceEvalParams& pep) { 
    /* ... */ 
}
```

or place the definition in the namespace:

```
namespace middleware {
    namespace calculus {
        PIType CalculatePI(const PerformanceEvalParams& pep) { 
            /* ... */ 
        }
    }
}
```